# Swagger generated twice when api definition is on a separate interface

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have generated, via codegen, the following interface:

```
/**
 * POST /pet : Add a new pet to the store
 *
 * @param petModel Pet object that needs to be added to the store (required)
 * @return Invalid input (status code 405)
 */
@ApiOperation(value = "Add a new pet to the store", nickname = "addPet", notes = "", tags={ "private", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid input") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/private/pet",
    consumes = { "application/json" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
default ResponseEntity<Void> addPet(@ApiParam(value = "Pet object that needs to be added to the store" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody PetModel petModel) throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

}
```

Then I make my controller implement it:

```
public class PetController implements Api{

    public ResponseEntity<Void> addPet(...
}
```

I also defined this docket:

```
@Bean
public Docket myApi(ServletContext servletContext) {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).pathProvider(new DefaultPathProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getOperationPath(String operationPath) {
            return StringUtils.substringAfter(super.getOperationPath(operationPath),contextPath) ;
        }

    })
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer()
{
    return new WebMvcConfigurer()
    {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry )
        {
            registry.addResourceHandler( "swagger-ui.html" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/" );
            registry.addResourceHandler( "/webjars/**" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" );
        }
    };
}
```

It works but, in the resulting swagger I get an empty row that is related to my controller.
Ho can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Its not becuase of interface, its because of TAG and not disabled default behavior - it would be the same if you would annotate implementation instead of interface.

Comment: What you mean by default behavior? I'd like to keep the tags for documentation